# Ionic/Angular: Preload content before transition animation

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a page that shows a list of asynchronously fetched users using `ng-repeat | orderby:'value'` .

The problem is that the first time the page is displayed, I see the elements appearing and getting sorted.

How can I force Ionic to load my view before I navigate to it?

Comment: Maybe you could use the routers resolve function: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use a "resolve" on the route. 
This can be done both with [ui-router resolve](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve) or with [ng-router](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider).

The disadvantage of using a "resolve" is that your page won't load until the data is available, however in your situation seems like that data is necessary before getting to the page.

Comment: Thanks, this works. The only problem is that `resolve` is executed every time i navigate to my page (also if it is cached) delaying the page transition every time (not only the first one).  
Is this the normal behaviour or am I doing something wrong? In case, is it possible to execute it once?

Comment: This is normal behaviour, I would suggest adding a "cache:true" parameter on your $http call, take a look here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#usage

Comment: alternatively you could use your own caching mechanism or use $cacheFactory

Comment: I'm using `firebase` as backend and `pouchdb` as local cache both wrapped in their own service. So none of the above is suitable for me, but thanks anyway :)
One more question: is there a way to use `resolve` in an angular component that is not a state?

Comment: Not really, the closest you can get to is this https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component#components-as-route-templates